# Keyword argument in python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument, args

```
class Car:
   def __int__(self, **kw):
          self.make = kw["make"]
          self.model = kw["model"]

my_car = Car(make="Nissan", model="GT-R")
print(my_car.model)
```

**TypeError: Car() takes no arguments, even though I initialized it as a multiple keyword argument**

Comment: You misspelled `__init__`, at least in the code you posted.

Comment: Try naming it `__init__(self, **kw)` because the code snippet you've supplied has a spelling error

Comment: Moreover, for readability, I would use` __init__(self, make, model)` `**kwargs` should be use only when you don’t know  combination of arguments that could  be passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled "init". That should fix it :)

Comment: I usually use comment field instead of answer field when notifying issues

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to leave a comment until I reach 50 reputation. It was a question bound to be closed, so I assumed it wouldn't matter :)